# Modifying onepage scroll functionality - overlap instead of slide up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Hi I am using this js library in order to make a site with full page scrolling.
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Here is my jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/aLjLjxux/

Instead of each element being pushed up and out of the body, I want them to stay fixed and be overlapped by the following divs. Is there a simple implementation for this functionality within this library, or is there a different library that will allow me to achieve this?

For reference it would look something like this:
http://www.facebookgroups.com/ except reversed. As in the divs that come later will overlap the previous divs on scroll.

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <section style="background-color: #eaeaea;" class="first"><h1>Hello</h1></section>
        <section style="background-color: #dadada;" class="second"><h1>Sup</h1></section>
        <section style="background-color: #cacaca;" class="third">yo</section>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".main").onepage_scroll({
           sectionContainer: "section",     // sectionContainer accepts any kind of selector in case you don't want to use section
           easing: "ease-out",                  // Easing options accepts the CSS3 easing animation such "ease", "linear", "ease-in",
                                            // "ease-out", "ease-in-out", or even cubic bezier value such as "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.420, 1.310)"
           animationTime: 1000,             // AnimationTime let you define how long each section takes to animate
           pagination: true,                // You can either show or hide the pagination. Toggle true for show, false for hide.
           updateURL: false,                // Toggle this true if you want the URL to be updated automatically when the user scroll to each page.
           beforeMove: function(index) {$(this).css("position", "fixed");},  // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called before the page moves.
           afterMove: function(index) {},   // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called after the page moves.
           loop: false,                     // You can have the page loop back to the top/bottom when the user navigates at up/down on the first/last page.
           keyboard: true,                  // You can activate the keyboard controls
           responsiveFallback: false,        // You can fallback to normal page scroll by defining the width of the browser in which
                                            // you want the responsive fallback to be triggered. For example, set this to 600 and whenever
                                            // the browser's width is less than 600, the fallback will kick in.
           direction: "vertical"            // You can now define the direction of the One Page Scroll animation. Options available are "vertical" and "horizontal". The default value is "vertical".  
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The website you link is using [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) plugin.
It even support old browsers with no CSS3 support, unlike the onepage-scroll you want to modify.

No need to modify the one you are using. It won't be that tribal anyway.

If you want to reverse it, then you should better start with pagePiling.js and you will have much less work.

Comment: awesome. thank you. however i am looking for something that instead of pushing the page up and out of view simply wipes over it to reveal the next div. any input on that?

Comment: Using `pagepiling`, how I can use `linear` easing? I tried `easing: 'linear'`, but doesn't work, seems like `pagepiling` doesn't respect to this setting.